# Failed to sign iOS Extension

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I've been building an app for the last couple of months that also has a Today Extension. Running this on my iPhone has always worked great. Until today, that is.

I keep getting `Failed to code sign "App Extension" None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices: myiPhone.`

I've tried creating new provision profiles and deleting then adding the UDID to my account again. Also, clicking `Fix issue` doesn't help. It just says that it can't fix it.

Nothing worked. It's only the extension that's throwing this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create app ID and provisioning profile for app extension.

1. need to make App ID for app extension in developer portal.
2. create 2 provisioning profile for host app and app extension.
3. sign app with app provisioning file and sign app extension with extension provisioning profile.

Good luck